# SVG to VML in Inkscape

Tags: internet-explorer, svg, export, vml, inkscape

I have an Inkscape SVG file, and I want export it to VML for web (Internet Explorer 8 and less don't work with svg). I need to do that automaticly and fast, because I work with lots of files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inkscape does not support the VML-format.

["While Microsoft continues to document VML, development of **the format ceased in 1998**."](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vml)

Instead of using a deprecated format, try to get around browser incompatibilities, using a JavaScript library like [svgweb](http://code.google.com/p/svgweb/) or [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/).

If you still want to convert to a stone-age file-format, I've found a German to-do: http://www.pixelfans.de/svg-in-vml-konvertieren/. Basically they export to OpenDocument Graphics (.odg), which results in losses of some kinds of graphic content, like gradients and then reopen that with Microsoft Office to save it as MS HTML or VML.